# Meaning of the g++ flags "-Wall", " -W", and "-Werror"

Tags: gcc-warning, compiler-flags

What are these and what do they do?

- -Wall
- -W
- -Werror

I am using the terminal in Ubuntu to compile programs with this command:

```
g++ -Wall -W -Werror main.cpp -o exec
```

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wall): enable a set of warning, but actually not all.
- `-W`: enable extra warnings. It's advised to use [`-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra) instead which has the same meaning
- [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror): every warning is treated as an error.

See GCC documentation:
*[3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options)*